# Implementing Kosaraju's algorithm to detect a cycle in a list of edges

Tags: python, directed-acyclic-graphs, directed-graph

I'm going off the pseudo code in this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm) but I can't seem to get it working to detect the SCCs or any cycles. Trying to detect cycles in a list of edges Any help is appreciated.

```py
class Solution:
    def canFinish(self, numCourses: int, prerequisites: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
        if len(prerequisites) == 0:
            return True
            
        adj = defaultdict(list)
        inv = defaultdict(list)
        for i, j in prerequisites:
            if i ==j: return False
            adj[j].append(i)
            inv[i].append(j)
        
        topo = []
        visited = set()
        def toposort(head):
            if head in visited: return
            visited.add(head)
            for neighbor in adj[head]:
                toposort(head)
            topo.append(head)
        
        for i in range(numCourses):
            toposort(i)

        assigned = set()
        scc = defaultdict(list)

        def kos(u, root):
            if u in assigned: return
            assigned.add(u)
            scc[root].append(u)
            for neighbor in inv[u]:
                kos(neighbor, root)
        
        for i in reversed(topo):
            kos(i, i)
        print(scc)
        return max(len(v) for v in scc.values()) <= 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your topological sort, inside the loop, you should pass the neighbor as an argument to `toposort`, not the current head node. Also, `kos` is not correctly traversing the graph in reverse order, it should be iterating over the neighbors of `u` in `inv[u]`, it is calling `kos(neighbor, root)` recursively with the same `u` parameter. Here's the code:

[**Playground Link**](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/online-python3-compiler/b5d6a812-0d92-455c-a08a-94b1787214f5):

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def canFinish(self, numCourses: int, prerequisites: List[List[int]]) -> bool:
        if len(prerequisites) == 0:
            return True
            
        adj = defaultdict(list)
        inv = defaultdict(list)
        for i, j in prerequisites:
            if i == j:
                return False
            adj[j].append(i)
            inv[i].append(j)
        
        topo = []
        visited = set()
        def toposort(head):
            if head in visited:
                return
            visited.add(head)
            for neighbor in adj[head]:
                toposort(neighbor)
            topo.append(head)
        
        for i in range(numCourses):
            toposort(i)

        assigned = set()
        scc = defaultdict(list)

        def kos(u, root):
            if u in assigned:
                return
            assigned.add(u)
            scc[root].append(u)
            for neighbor in inv[u]:
                kos(neighbor, root)
        
        for i in reversed(topo):
            if i not in assigned:
                kos(i, i)

        for component in scc.values():
            if len(component) > 1:
                return False

        return True
        
solution = Solution()
print(solution.canFinish(2, [[1,0]])) # True
print(solution.canFinish(2, [[1,0],[0,1]])) # False

print(solution.canFinish(3, [[0,1],[0,2],[1,2]])) # True
print(solution.canFinish(3, [[0,1],[1,2]])) # True

print(solution.canFinish(4, [[1,0],[2,1],[3,2],[1, 3]])) # False
print(solution.canFinish(4, [[1,0],[2,1],[3,2],[3, 1]])) # True
```